# Draw Cosx with specific period width

Tags: c#, drawing, trigonometry

how can i draw a period of  Cosx with width =100 and height 50?

my recent code is very hard to control them :(

```
// this to find y with each x to draw Cos
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 50; i += 1, j++)
{
    int y = (int)((Math.Cos((double)i * height/10F * Math.PI / cy) + 1.0) * (cx - 1) / widtd/10F);
    poi.SetValue(new Point(i, y),j);  // poi is an aray of point
}
```

Comment: You're not drawing anything here, simply assigning values. The implementation of your drawing is what determines how your wave will look. How are you drawing `poi`?

Comment: i'm using Graphics.DrawLines(), my question is how to control height and width of cos wave, I forgot many thing of Math :(

Comment: What do you define as "width"? You can draw a cosine function 100 pixels wide, but varying the frequency will produce a denser or coarser wave. What is your desired frequency?

Comment: forget about above code :)
y = 100*sin(x/20)^2
will give me a sin with 100 height and 60 width ?

Comment: There is no such thing as width here. The width depends on your input domain. That function goes from -inf to +inf.

Comment: sorry but my "width" here is width of "a wave in cos path", i don't know how to decrible it exactly in english

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's last comment I assume "width" means a single period. Therefore to calculate the points of a cosine function with amplitude `amp` and a period of `period` looks like this:

```
int amp = 50, period = 100;
Point[] poi = new Point[period];
for (int x = 0; x < period; x++)
{
    int y = (int)(amp * Math.Cos(x * 2 * Math.PI * (1.0 / period)));
    poi[x] = new Point(x, y);
}
```

Note that this is a "1:1" calculation, i.e. one point is one pixel.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here:

```
string filename = @"D:\test.bmp";
        int width = 200;
        int height = 300;
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(width, height);

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            int y = (int)((Math.Cos((double)i * 2.0 * Math.PI / width) + 1.0) * (height - 1) / 2.0);
            b.SetPixel(i, y, Color.Black);
        }
        b.Save(filename);
```