# Zoom function in python? (2.7.9)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, trigonometry

I'm currently working with the turtle library of python.

I'm working on my midterm project for my coding class and my project is to draw cos, sin, and tangent curves using turtle as well as their inverse functions.

My problem is that when I'm coding inverse sin, the graph shows up way too small and is impossible to be seen by the user. I was wondering if there was a zoom function or a way to stretch the graph to make it bigger?

Here is my code for `arcsin`:

```
def drawarcsincurve(amplitude, period, horShift, verShift):
    turtle.speed(0)
    startPoint = -1 
    turtle.goto(startPoint, math.asin(startPoint))
    turtle.pendown()
    for angles in range(-1,1):
        y = math.asin(angles)
        turtle.goto(angles,y)
```

Comment: You don't need to zoom, just increase your amplitude. Use a scaling value and multiply it by your function's output: `y = 10 * math.sin(angles)`  the value 10 is just an example. You can use any value you see fit.

Comment: Right, I actually tried that initially but all that gives me is just a longer line that looks like a very squished together arcsine curve. Thank you for the response btw. @reculated Spline

Comment: You will also have to expand in the horizontal (x) direction as well. I just noticed you have two parameters to the function `amplitude` and `period`. Make use of these parameters.

Comment: So are you suggesting I change it to y= amplitude * math.sin(angles/amplitude)??

Comment: No; you don't want to use `amplitude` in your `sin` function. You will want to use `period`. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27644155/2544158).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem here, I think, is the range over which your are iterating your `angles` variable.  The line

```
for angles in range(-1,1):
```

will execute the loop only twice, with `angle == 1` and `angle == 0` - i.e. it is equivalent to using

```
for angles in [-1,0]:
```

Type `range(-1,1)` in a Python interpreter window to see what I mean.

You might be getting confused over names as well.  You call your loop variable `angles`, but it's actually representing a ratio (the sine value whose inverse you are calculating).

What you probably want really is something that iterates over the range `-1` to `1` in fairly small steps.  Lets choose `0.01` as our step (that's arbitrary)

I've altered your code directly rather than doing my own implementation.

1. I've put in a scale factor (`plot_scale`) which is equivalent to the zoom that I think you want in your original question.
2. I've left your original function arguments in, although I don't use them.  I thought you might want to play with them later.

---

```
def drawarcsincurve(amplitude, period, horShift, verShift):
    plot_scale = 100 # Arbitrary value - up to you - similar to "zoom"
    turtle.speed(1)
    turtle.penup() 
    startPoint = -1 
    turtle.goto(plot_scale*startPoint, plot_scale*math.asin(startPoint))
    turtle.pendown()
    for angles in range(-100,100):
        sinval = 1.0 * angles / 100 # this will run -1 to 1 in 0.01 steps
        y = math.asin(sinval)
        turtle.goto(plot_scale*sinval,plot_scale*y)
```

This outputs:

[image: Plot of arcsin curve on Python Tk graphics]